# Why can I not create a blank solution without creating a directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Is it just me or does anyone else find it annoying in Visual Studio when you go to create a new blank solution, Visual Studio greys out the "Create directory for solution" option meaning you are always forced to create a new directory?

I'm [aware of the workarounds](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/c1579334-2b06-4c51-a8d1-7e3443b7e843), but this still seems a fundamentally missing feature. Does anyone know if this is fixed in VS 2010?

Comment: This is really annoying, especially in VS 2015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pesky thing, true. There is a workaround you may find useful: <s>http://flux88.com/blog/right-click-new-visual-studio-solution/</s> http://benscheirman.com/2009/03/right-click-new-visual-studio-solution

It sets things up so that you can right-click an open folder in Explorer and choose new->visual studio solution. I appreciate the shortcut when creating new projects, largely for experimentation, so I want to get moving quickly.

Comment: Interesting- I hadn't seen that one before. I have exactly the same folder structure as the guy- no surprise there as I am using Subversion. I'll look into it more tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Grant- this is good enough until they change the behaviour in Visual Studio. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you approve. I find this functionality nicely fills the mentioned gap in VS functionality.

Comment: Link that works http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2005/10/25/ShellNew-Extension-for-Visual-Studio-Solutions/ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673370/create-vs2010-solution-from-windows-explorer-context-menu

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Apparently the author of the linked site moved his blog, I updated the link

Comment: All the links to the registry key are broken. :( So I made a gist. https://gist.github.com/4273589

Comment: Sad that this is still needed in Visual Studio 12

Answer (score -1):

The link above doesn't seem to work any more so here's a new one: http://geekswithblogs.net/blomqvist/archive/2010/04/19/new-blank-solution-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: The page you are referring to does not solve the above problem of a folder being created