# Create VS2010 Solution from Windows explorer context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to add an item to the Windows Explorer context menu that will enable me to create a new vs2010 solution in the currently selected folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like this has been answered. Here is what I found that will do just as you ask:

<strike>http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/ShellNew-Extension-for-Visual-Studio-Solutions.aspx</strike>.
new url: http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2005/10/25/ShellNew-Extension-for-Visual-Studio-Solutions/

I find it easier to create blank solutions using the right-click context menu because of the way I want to organize my file structure.  Once I have a blank solution, I open it and add projects to it.  This method gives me more control and is easier to manage.

EDIT: not finished...then browse to C:\Windows\ShellNew and create a new file named Visual Studio Solution.sln edit it with a text editor like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Global
  GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
  EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Link to zip file contained in the `peterprovost.org` link is dead. List of ways to register template for use in context menu. Summary: add string value to registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sln\ShellNew\FileName` set to `Visual Studio Solution.sln` or whatever the name of your template is. Template must be in `C:\Windows\ShellNew`.

Comment: see this for regedit details: https://superuser.com/a/1284919/72673  `c:\windows\ShellNew` does not exist in Windows 10